# Registry/Environment path problems with JDK/JRE

Tags: path, jvm, java

Greeting all. I come from a C++ background, but I wanted to give Java a try, and have been reading a book. Now comes the JDK, though. Basically, what I want to do is make it so I can rearrange/rename folders, and not make this break. I think the problem is specifically somewhere within the JRE and the JVM - specifically, if I rearrange stuff, it says it cannot fing the jvm.config file, using the path that it had been previously, which is logical - it is no longer there. My question is, how do you CHANGE this behavior so it, eh, works. I found a similar question on a SO site (I forget which one, probably here) detailing nearly the same problem. It was something about the... installer, perhaps? Or something, adding some sort of registry path, as I understand it. (JavaHome mabye?). The linked to reference, or the answer, however, did not make it clear to me how to fix this. And thus, here I am.

For example, let's say my directory goes kind of like this (or, rather, went) ...\Program\Java...

and within was the jre. I changed the Program to Programming - might be bad practice, but I felt urged to change it. Point is, it no longer worked unless I kept it like it was before. Ideally, I actually want all the JDK related file, including the JRE, all in a JDK folder. And, of course, any other movements I make. How do I fix this path problem?

Thanks if you can help.

Comment: Did you set the PATH variable in your environmental variables?

Comment: How about reinstalling everything and giving the correct paths at installation time to save future headache? (why would installation path matter anyway?) You can always have a Program/Java folder, with JDK and JRE subfolders.

Comment: Many words. Not clear to me what the problem is. In any case, re-install. I guess you're in Windows? JRE registers itself during installation, and you moved it out from under that.

Comment: I did reinstall, the first time. Then I changed it again... it gets real tiring, and I was just thinking, there must be an easier way. Perhaps not. Unfortunate.

Answer (score 0):

The JDK has an embedded JRE, you can move the JRE and JDK directories to different parts of the file system and they will still work, but changing the layout within JRE & JDK will not work.